# How to force English decimal format in a Django app with language specified as French

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm running into this situation that I don't know what to do: In my app template, I'm returning a number with two decimal places:

```
{{ number }}
```

say if I return 1000.00, in `en` it will just be `1000.00` whereas in `fr` it will give me `1000,00` with a comma. And now here is the problem, I need to get this value in JavaScript to do a front end graph in d3, and JavaScript recognizes `1000,00` as two separate numbers. So how can I force the returning value to be `1000.00` regardless of what the current language is in Django?

Comment: Does `{{ repr(number) }}` work? (I don't know django formatting)

Comment: Try `{{ number|stringformat:"f" }}`

Answer (score 3):

From Django's [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/formatting/#std:templatefilter-unlocalize), you can remove localization by doing

```
{% load l10n %}

{{ value|unlocalize }}
```